Why am I getting a different IPv6 address than expected when pinging my WAN interface?
I am trying to ping my router's WAN interface from outside the local network, that is from a device connected to the internet.
I enabled the "enable pinging WAN interface" option in my router's configuration, but I am having an issue finding which one is the correct WAN interface address.
This is what my WAN configuration looks like:



Is the IPv6 address the correct WAN interface address?
WhatisMyIP tells me that my IP is different than what's in the configuration. So, which IP is the right one, if any of those two is?

Yes that’s your router’s address. What’s your goal? Just pinging the router to check whether the connection is alive or something?

@DanielB Learning basic networking and I'd like to try that it really works. But it does not work. I'm not getting a response. It says unknown host. I'm trying to ping from ConnectBot app on my android phone. Maybe it's not compatible with IPv6 addresses?

Try pinging from a device you absolutely know supports IPv6

IPv6 works very differently to IPv4. With IPv4 you need port forwarding, with IPv6 you can open up your local pc directly to the internet. I suspect the IPv6 address of WhatIsMyIP may actually be your local IPv6 address, not your router's one.

@LPChip Confusing. I thought WAN interface stands between internet and local network. And the actual IP that's on WhatsMyIP is something assigned by the IP and stands before WAN Interface. But apparently I still don't know enough.

I think it's more that you learned things backwards – instead of learning how IP works in general and adding NAT on top of that, you've learned NAT first (from your home connection) and are now assuming that it must always work like that.

@grawity_u1686 Thanks, I'll continue studying.


WhatisMyIP tells me that my IP is different than what's in the configuration. So, which IP is the right one, if any of those two is?

The address reported by your router is indeed your router's WAN address.
What the WhatisMyIP website shows isn't the router's address, it's your computer's, because your computer is the one connecting to the website.
This is usually different between IPv4 and IPv6, because in IPv4 your ISP cannot afford to assign more than one address per customer – having just one "WAN" address isn't an inherent limitation of IP; it's rather a workaround devised due to there being more hosts than addresses available. That is not the case with IPv6, though, and your ISP can assign not only a WAN address for the router but also a whole address block for your LAN as well.
So when your computer connects to WhatisMyIP over IPv4, the router necessarily has to replace its (private) IP address with the router's own (public) one, but with IPv6 that is not necessary – the computer already has a public address of its own – and therefore websites see its actual address, not the router's.
Additionally: If your router's status page is showing only IPv6 and not IPv4, it could be that your ISP hasn't assigned you any public IPv4 address at all – due to the same reason of IPv4 shortage. In the simplest case the router might still have WAN IPv4 address but from a private range (meaning there are two layers of NAT), which the ISP's firmware just hides from you; in more complex cases the WAN connection might actually be purely IPv6 with v4-to-v6 translation happening on both ends.

Hello, when I open WhatsMyIp, it shows different IPv6 address than the one that is my router's WAN IPv6 address. How is it possible?

Already explained in the post. The phone already has its own IPv6 address, so there is no need for it to be turned into the router's address.

I see. I checked ipconfig in my terminal and indeed the IPv6 address that is shown on WhatsMyIp is listed as Temporary IPv6 Address under Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi, as I am connected to the router via Wi-Fi.
It's a difficult topic for me to understand. I'll think about your post, thanks!

Ignore the 'Temporary' label; it's there for a different reason – just focus on the fact that every device has its own public IP address, so the router never needs to overwrite it. The same concept used to exist in IPv4 (and still does, in places that have enough addresses); it's how IP began.

Interesting. One more question - I can't find the displayed WhatsMyIp IPv4 address. It's not shown on the router's configuration page or in the details listed by ipconfig. I'm using Windows and when I open View network connections and view the properties of Internet protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4), the IP configuration is set as Obtain an IP address automatically. Is it something that happens outside of my computer's or router's configuration (unless I manually choose a specific IP through the second option - Use the following IP address) as it is assigned by the Internet Provider?

When you get only a single IPv4 address (i.e. when you use NAT), it won't be in the computer's ipconfig because it's not assigned to the computer directly – it's assigned to the router, while the computer only obtains a private address from the router (not from the ISP). That is to say, "your public address" is specifically just the router's address – it isn't duplicated across the whole LAN. Your computer and your phone etc. are completely unaware of it being there; the router does all the work of swapping it in as packets go through it.

Thank you very much for explaining this to me.

So in both cases your computer obtains addresses from the router (both v4 and v6), but in the v4 case the router offers addresses from a private-use range while in v6 the router gets a public range from the ISP and offers addresses from it. (Again, this isn't necessarily how IPv4 has to work, but it's what we ended up having to do, due to the IPv4 address shortage.)

In fact some ISPs are so short on IPv4 addresses that they don't even give customers one anymore, so it's possible that the v4 address shown by WhatisMyIP won't show up anywhere else at all. This varies from ISP to ISP; I had to pay mine $2 to get a public WAN IPv4 address.

It could be my case with the IPv4 because when I enter my router's configuration via 192.168.0.1, it shows only IPv6 address. You're saying in the v4 case the router offers addresses from a private-use range. Does that mean that the use-range is private to my Internet Provider, i.e. I can't know the actual v4 until it's assigned, unlike with v6 that I can check in the router's configuration?

The private 192.168.0.0/24 IPv4 range that your computers get addresses from is actually private to you – it is set in your router's configuration (for the LAN interface, as well as DHCP settings), with the ISP being unaware of it. The router, having addresses from both sides, acts as the boundary between your LAN's private addresses and the public-addressed WAN side. Normally, though, the router would get a public IPv4 address for its WAN interface in the same way as it gets the IPv6 address – you would see both v4 and v6 WAN addresses in its config as soon as it connects to the ISP.

So if your router doesn't show the LAN IPv4 settings, you can probably assume that the ISP tweaked its firmware to hide those (fewer support calls? idk), and if the router doesn't show the WAN IPv4 address [but you definitely have IPv4 access to Internet], then you can probably assume that 1) the ISP is one of those which don't give out public IPv4 addresses anymore, and there's most likely a more complex setup behind the scenes, like CGNAT or DS-Lite or 464XLAT, sou you indeed can't know your public IPv4 address upfront anymore; 2) the ISP hid all of that from the configuration as well.

Thank you! I'd welcome if you had some teaching materials for sale. I'd definitely buy from you.
